# How can I bypass Firefox's SSL certificate warning with Selenium 4.10.0 Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, automation, ssl-certificate

I been trying to automate a process using Selenium 4.10.0 with Python on a website that uses a self-signed SSL certificate. But I keep running into the SSL warning.

Self-signed cert warning photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T0Pb.png)

I have tried various things to try to bypass the warning such as:

Modifying the options for the Firefox() class

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=profile)
driver.get(url_here)
```

Using the capabilities method in the FirefoxOptions() class

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = "True"
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_capability('about:config', {'acceptInsecureCerts': True})
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(url_here)
```

Following Mozilla's method (similar to the one above)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions

session = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities={"acceptInsecureCerts": True})
session.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/")
print(session.current_url)
```

I have also tried looking at other people's Stack overflow posts but none of them seem to work for me.

At this point, should I start looking into a way of just adding the self-signed .pem file as a trusted cert for the browser via Selenium?

Comment: there are dangers in accepting non certified certs.  The root-CAs will verify that this is indeed the site that the cert is generated for.... without that, you have no guarantee that another site or middle-man is using the same cert.  (So if you decide to trust the cert, you may be adding trust to multiple sites...)

Comment: @pcalkins 
Yep, I am well aware of that. I am just automating a website that's within an intranet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out my own question. The following worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.set_preference("accept_insecure_certs", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

driver.get(url_here)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).